# Problem using LinearAccelerationSensor, Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, accelerometer

I'm using Unity.
I want to get user device's (mobile phone's) acceleration without gravity.
I found [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.LinearAccelerationSensor.html) bout new input system, and LinearAccelerationSensor seems like it's what I need but I don't get how to use it.

Here's code I've tried to use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using TMPro;
 
public class AccelerometerDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI debugText;
    private LinearAccelerationSensor linearAccelerationSensor;
    Vector3 linearAcceleration;
 
    void Update()
    {
        if (linearAccelerationSensor == null)
        {
            // Attempt to get the LinearAccelerationSensor
            linearAccelerationSensor = InputSystem.GetDevice<LinearAccelerationSensor>();
            if (linearAccelerationSensor != null)
            {
                debugText.text = "Linear Acceleration Sensor found!";
            }
            else
            {
                debugText.text = "Linear Acceleration Sensor not found.";
                return;
            }
        }
 
        linearAcceleration = linearAccelerationSensor.acceleration.ReadValue();
 
        debugText.text = linearAcceleration.x + " " + linearAcceleration.y + " " + linearAcceleration.z ;
    }
}
```

I tried on both Unity Play and built on my mobile phone and on both it always shows `Linear Acceleration Sensor not found.`. What I'm doing wrong?